# Type declaration clarification

Tags: c#-4.0

I am new to C#. When we declare a statement like this

```
var list = new { FirstName = "Jon", LastName ="Doz" }; .
```

I am not supplying any type in declaration. How does compiler accept it without throwing an error.

I mean `new <without type>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx)

C# compiler converts it in the background into a more verbose declaration, such as this:

```
class __Anonymous1
{
   private string firstName ;
   private string lastName;
   public string FirstName{get { return firstName; } set { firstName = value ;} }
   public string LastName{ get { return lastName; } set { lastName= value ; } }
}
__Anonymous1 list = new __Anonymous1();
list.FirstName = "Jon";
list.LastName ="Doz";
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually creating an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx), a sort of temporary class that only has those fields that you declared.

Note that `var` isn't doing this. `var` just does type inferencing, so you could say `var list = new List<int>();` and it wouldn't create an anonymous type. It's the `new {...}` that is responsible for the temporary class creation. However, using `var` is the only way to store it in a variable, since anonymous types don't have names.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an anonymous type. It's simply an object belonging to a type with no name, and having those two properties you gave it.

You can read more about anonymous types here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As @IanHenry stated, you are creating an Anonymous Type.  They were created to support LINQ and are readonly.  This means if you create an anonymous type like the one in your question, you cannot update any of the values.

Answer (score 0):

This concept is knows as [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx). From MSDN:

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first. The type name is generated by the compiler and is
>   not available at the source code level. The type of each property is
>   inferred by the compiler.